# Why do I get a SSL Expired error for certificates that are still valid?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

I have a server that hosts a Java backend which has a JavaKeyStore (JKS) that stores a certificate from Lets Encrypt.

The certificate chain looks as follows:

- ISRG Root X1 (valid until 30/09/2024, 20:14:03 CEST)
-- R3           (valid until 15/09/2025, 18:00:00 CEST)
--- api.verumsoftware.com (valid until 31/10/2021, 23:10:36 CET)

When I make a request in Postman I get the following error:

> SSL Error: Certificate has expired

I find this odd since each certificate in the chain should still be valid.
Does anybody know what could cause this? When I look up the server on various sites that check whether certificates are correctly installed, they all say it's perfectly fine.

Comment: https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/

Answer (score 1):

This is a LetsEncrypt issue that occurred on Sep 30 2021.  You probably need to patch the OS to remove the offending certificate.

For example this in CentOS.
https://blog.devgenius.io/rhel-centos-7-fix-for-lets-encrypt-change-8af2de587fe4#:%7E:text=So%2C%20DST%20Root%20CA%20X3%20needs%20to%20be,The%20manual%20steps%20below%20are%20no%20longer%20necessary

Or use a non-LetsEncrypt SSL Cert.

Comment: Yea, apparently it was a major issue for a lot of different services. In my case an API that was being called by a Filemaker service. Filemaker patched the issue and it all works perfectly again.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this was an issue with Postman, details can be found here:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/10338

Updating Postman to version 9.0.5 fixed the issue for me!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple fix: install this "new" R3 certificate on the CLIENT -- So, on your iPhone (or other iOS device), PC/Mac, browser ect (tested only of Apple, but should work for Android,ect)

1. GoTO https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/
2. find the bullet `Let’s Encrypt R3` (below active)
3. Click on the link called *pem* (or one of the other types; try a bit for your device)
4. It will download the cert and/or offer to install it

- On iPhone (etc)

  - Use 'Setting'
  - A new entry is shown, about the cert
  - follow it, accept it
  - Done
- On Mac

  - The file is downloaded
  - Open: KeyChain acces
  - File-> Import
  - Select the file; eg: *~/Downloads/let-encript-r3.pem*
  - follow, etc
  - optionally: select/config SSL: always trust
  - Done

In general, there is **NO** need to install/update software, just one file :-)